# Android theme text color conflicts with alert dialog title color

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am customizing my android app by defining theme in `styles.xml`. I would like to apply a basic text color to all text of my app, but I want to keep the appearance of `AlertDialog` as default (Holo.Light).

> styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/DialogWindowTitleAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogWindowTitleAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

However, the color defined in `AppTheme` overrides the purple color:

[image]

If I remove the line `<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>` in `AppTheme`, the text color of the title changes correctly.
[image]

**So my question is: How can I define a text color for my app theme, while setting another color (or preserving system default color) to the dialog title text?**

Answer (score 1):

define

```
<item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">...</item>
```

in your AlertDialogStyle

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped, i only specified windowTitleStyle and for the color it doesn't work without android:textAppearanceLarge too

Answer (score 0):

in Your AndroidManifest.xml set another **style** to your Activity

```
<activity
    android:name="com.my.sample.Activity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/my_activity_name">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Great work with drilling down to the specific text you want to change.  The fact it isn't working looks like a bug to me.  If you want a built-in alert dialog window instead of a custom themed one, you can use this function when you build an alert box:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int theme)
```

"theme" can be AlertDialog.ThemeTraditional or some other AlertDialog theme constant.  I imagine you've moved on by now, maybe making your own alert dialog activity to replace it, but the above was an adequate workaround for me (I had white text on light grey background, so I had to do something).